# position text respect menu

Tags: html, css

I have menú in my web of margin left, but I want put text in the next of menú, of the left relative this. But I make a div in css and this put below of menú.
What position I need put?
I have a div inside other div.

```
example code this:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a70aabub/

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try posting your code sample/css vis jsfiddle for better clarity. Your question does not provide details that help in providing answers.

Comment: @bbh I edit with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float:left` for text class.

```
#menu ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 200px;
float:left
}
#menu ul li {
    background-color: #999;
}
#state {
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    float:left
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/a70aabub/1/